# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{{\rho}\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\log{(1-(a^{-\rho}+b^{-\rho}-(ab)^{-\rho}))}}{\log{\rho}} $ with $a>1$ and $b>1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate this question?
$$\lim\limits_{{\rho}\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\log{(1-(a^{-\rho}+b^{-\rho}-(ab)^{-\rho}))}}{\log{\rho}} ,$$
where $a>1$ and $b>1$.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: You need one more ")".

Comment: thx, i have added ")".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that you have $(1-a^{-\rho})(1-b^{-\rho})$
inside the logarithm in the denominator, and that
$$
\frac{d}{d\rho}a^{-\rho}=
\frac{d}{d\rho}e^{-\rho\ln a}=
-e^{-\rho\ln a}\cdot\ln a=
-a^{-\rho}\ln a.
$$
So
$$
\begin{align}L&=
\lim_{\rho\to0^+}
\frac{\log{(1-(a^{-\rho}+b^{-\rho}-(ab)^{-\rho}))}}{\log{\rho}}
\\&=\lim_{\rho\to0^+}
\frac{\log(1-e^{-\rho\ln a})+\log(1-e^{-\rho\ln b})}{\log{\rho}}
\\&\stackrel*=\lim_{\rho\to0^+}
\rho\left[
\frac{a^{-\rho}\ln a}{1-a^{-\rho}}+
\frac{b^{-\rho}\ln b}{1-b^{-\rho}}
\right]
\\&=\lim_{\rho\to0^+}
\frac{\rho\ln a}{a^\rho-1}+
\frac{\rho\ln b}{b^\rho-1}
\\&\stackrel*=\lim_{\rho\to0^+}
\frac{\ln a}{a^\rho\ln a}+
\frac{\ln b}{b^\rho\ln b}
\\&=2
\end{align}
$$
where we have used L'Hopital's Rule ($*$) twice and algebra on the remaining lines. Finally, note that while my derivation assumes that
$\log=\ln$ are both base $e$, the answer is the same if $\log$
is base $10$ because
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log_{10} x
=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\ln x}{\ln 10}
=\frac1{x\ln 10},$$
and the two factors of $\ln 10$ would cancel out after the first
application of L'Hopital's Rule.

The original post suggested the answer should be $1$.
Such a proposed result might be the consequence
of erroneously arriving at
$$\frac{\ln a+\ln b}{\ln a+\ln b}\ne
\frac{\ln a}{\ln a}+\frac{\ln b}{\ln b}.$$

Comment: thank you for answering, the source may wrong, i would fix the question.

Answer (score 2):

Using the expansions

$$e^z=1+z+\frac12 z^2+O(z^3)$$

and

$$\log(1+x)=O(x)$$

we can write

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(1-a^{-\rho}-b^{-\rho}+(ab)^{-\rho}\right)&=\log\left(1-e^{-\log(a)\rho}-e^{-\log(b)\rho}+e^{-\log(ab)\rho}\right)\\\\
&=\log\left(\log(a)\log(b)\rho^2+O(\rho^3)\right)\\\\
&=\log(\log(a)\log(b)\rho^2)+O(\rho)\\\\
&=\log(\log(a)\log(b))+2\log(\rho)+O(\rho)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\lim_{\rho\to 0^+}\frac{\log\left(1-a^{-\rho}-b^{-\rho}+(ab)^{-\rho}\right)}{\log(\rho)}=2$$

Comment: I still can't understand why $(1-e^{-\log(a)\rho}-e^{-\log(b)\rho}+e^{-\log(ab)\rho}) = (\log(a)\log(b)\rho^2+O(\rho^3))$

Comment: If we replace each $e^{-\log(c)\rho}$ with $1-\log(c)\rho$ inside the outer logarithm (for $c=a,b,ab$), all constant and linear (in $\rho$) terms vanish. Adding in the $\rho^2$ terms, we get $$\frac{\rho^2}2\left[(\log a+\log b)^2-(\log a)^2-(\log b)^2\right],$$ giving @Dr.MV's result.

Comment: thx, but why $O(\rho^3)$ becomes $O(\rho)$ after it came out the function $\log()$, @bgins

Comment: $\log(c+x)=\log\left(c\left(1+\frac{x}{c}\right)\right)=\log(c)+O(x)$, for $c>0$ and $x>0$ near $0$, so $$\log\left(\log(a)\log(b)\rho^2+O(\rho^3)\right)$$ $$=\log(\rho^2)+\log\left(\log(a)\log(b)+O(\rho)\right)$$ $$=\log(\rho^2)+\log\left(\log(a)\log(b)\right)+O(\rho)$$ with $c=\log(a)\log(b)$. Then, since $\log(\rho)\to-\infty$, these terms dominate the numerator and denominator giving the result.

Comment: thanks for answering, l learn a lot from this problem @bgins

Answer (score 2):

Factoring the argument of $\log$ we can see that the numerator can be written as $$\log(1-a^{-\rho})+\log(1-b^{-\rho})$$ and note that we have $$\lim_{\rho\to 0^{+}}\frac{a^{\rho}-1}{\rho}=\log a$$ which implies that $$\lim_{\rho\to 0^{+}}\frac{1-a^{-\rho}}{\rho\log a}=1$$ We can now write $$\frac{\log(1-a^{-\rho})}{\log\rho} = \dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{1-a^{-\rho}}{\rho\log a}\right)+\log\rho +\log\log a}{\log\rho} = 1 +\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{1-a^{-\rho}}{\rho\log a}\right) +\log\log a}{\log\rho}$$ so that this expression tends to $1$ as $\rho\to 0^{+}$. Similarly $\dfrac{\log(1-b^{-\rho})}{\log\rho} \to 1$ as $\rho\to 0^{+}$. Hence the desired limit is $1+1=2$. The answer is valid even when $0<a,b<1$ but then the numerator needs to be split as $$\log(a^{-\rho}-1)+\log(b^{-\rho}-1)$$